# PHP cURL cookies blocking

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

```
<?php

$ebay_user_id = "id"; // Please set your Ebay ID
$ebay_user_password = "password"; // Please set your Ebay Password
$cookie_file_path = dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt'; // Please set your Cookie File path

$LOGINURL = "http://signin.ebay.com/aw-cgi/eBayISAPI.dll?SignIn";
$agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)";
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$LOGINURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$LOGINURL = "http://signin.ebay.com/aw-cgi/eBayISAPI.dll";
$POSTFIELDS = 'MfcISAPICommand=SignInWelcome&siteid=0&co_partnerId=2&UsingSSL=0&ru=&pp=&pa1=&pa2=&pa3=&i1=-1&pageType=-1&userid='. $ebay_user_id .'&pass='. $ebay_user_password;
$reffer = "http://signin.ebay.com/aw-cgi/eBayISAPI.dll?SignIn";

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$LOGINURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$POSTFIELDS); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $reffer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch); 
print   $result;    ?>
```

I'm really new player on cURL...

I have this code now using in login into ebay.

The problem for now is the cookies it told me that it was blocked by something.

The message it shows: Your web browser settings are blocking cookies.

I use firefox for test and tried other browser also got the same issues.

I have confirmed that my browser setting are accepted for the cookies access.

Also, I have checked there has conntent inside the cookies.txt file, so that mean the cookies.txt can be access correctly.

So....What is the problem for this issue? The code I used are correct?
Thanks everyone for help.

Comment: it might be that ebay is sending another cookie with javascript to prevent automation, but I am not sure. Compare the cookies after the log in with real browser and the cookies in cookies.txt

Comment: oh, and if I call your script and check the output, I have to enter a captcha...

Answer (score 3):

Try modifying the agent to something similar;

```
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1'
```

Edit: actually I believe the problem is you need to query the signin page first,
first visit "http://signin.ebay.com/aw-cgi/eBayISAPI.dll?SignIn"
this will set the cookies, then sign in as you have.

you can try it in a browser, navigate to the eBay sign in page,
clear your cookies and then signin.
You will get the browser not supporting cookies error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand something and that is that doing a HTTP request with curl through php has nothing to do with your browser. The website you are accessing doesn't care what browser you use to run the php script. The actual request is done by your server, not by your browser.

On the other hand, if eBay engineers are smart they'd block this, you probably aren's supposed to do things like this, that's what the [Ebay API's](http://developer.ebay.com/common/api/) are for.

And a little tip, use a HTTP Client library, doing things like this in plain cURL is a pita and gives some very bad and unreadable code.

Check https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle for example.

Comment: you mean using curl is not good for login? In case, i just want to use the curl for post the login data to the authentication page and let it authenticate itself. If not, are there any way for doing such thing in PHP?

Comment: No curl is perfect for doing this, it's just that eBay probably doesn't want tools to login to their web frontend, that's not what the web frontend is made for. The web frontend is made for real users behind their computer logging in. If you are making software that automates eBay in some way you should be using their API, not pretending to be a real user.